# Remove rows where column contains specific text

Tags: c#, arrays, .net, linq

I want to remove all the rows of the data whose columns  contains `?` e.g. in around 100 rows for Column Status I am getting value as `Unknown?`, `Error?`, `InProgress`, `Done`

So , I want to remove all the rows which contains `?`

Below are the code I am using

```
//I am splitting the string on the basis of delimeter  ,

 var data = from val in UserData
                       select val.Split(',');
//Below code is not working

var filterdata = from rows in data
                        where rows.Contains("?")
                        select rows;
```

Comment: 1. What is the type of `rows`? 2. What does the `Contains` method on that type do? 3. If you want to _filter out_ rows containing values containing `"?"`, why are you using `where` to include them?

Comment: @NetMage sorry it was my bad i forgot to use the !.It is not filtering because I am getting  column values like Error? but i am using contains with ? which is looking for exact text Error?

Comment: Can you answer/think about my other questions?

Comment: @NetMage 1-rows is returning an array collection with around 5 columns 2- Contains method is just filtering or removing the rows if it contains ?

Comment: Programming is about precision. `Split(char)` returns a `string[]`. `Array.Contains` does what exactly?

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to invert the contains:

```
string[] someStringArray = new string[]
{
    "\"ABC\" ,\"Error?\",\"OK\"",
    "\"DEF\",\"Inprogress\",\"FINE\"",
    "1,2,3",
    "?,2,3",
    "1,?,3",
    "4,5,6"
};

//I am splitting the string on the basis of delimeter  ,

var data = from val in someStringArray
            select val.Split(',');
//Below code is not working

var filterdata = from rows in data
                    where !rows.Contains("?") // "!" to select the rows WITHOUT "?"
                    select rows;

foreach (var item in filterdata)
{
    foreach (var i in item)
    {
        Console.Write(i + ",");
    }
    Console.WriteLine();
}

return;
```

Result:

```
"DEF","Inprogress","FINE",
4,5,6,
```

This code is perfectly working, I think.

Beside this, I doing a wild guess: You're not searching for quesionmarks "?". The "?" is a character which is often shown if the character can't be shown in your expected encoding.

Have a look which number your chars have:

```
var chars = someStringArray.SelectMany(s => s.Select(c => c));

foreach (var item in chars.GroupBy(g => g.ToString() + " (" + ((int)g) + ")"))
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + ": " + item.Count());
}
```

Real questionmarks have a 63. If not you've got encoding problems..

Comment: Thanks for your help it is not filtering because it is not taking ? as a character when i hardcoded like Error? it filters well. Do you know what would be the best way to filter the character ? because when i am using single quotes it is giving error

Comment: If it is not working i need Info: Show more code. Show example-data which shows the problem.

Comment: I am getting the data like [0] -->"ABC" ,"Error?","OK"  [1]-->"DEF","Inprogress","FINE"

Comment: 1. edit your question. Don't comment example data. 2. Added your data to my solution: It works. Did you try my code?  3. I still think the '?' you see is not a questionmark.

Answer (score 0):

You wrote:

> I want to remove all the rows of the data whose columns contains "?"

You can never change the input sequence using LINQ functions. So you can't remove rows from your original data using LINQ.

What you can do, is use your data to create a new sequence that doesn't contain question marks. If desired, you can replace your original data with the new sequence.

Looking at your code, it seems that `UserData` is a sequence of strings, of which you expect that these strings contains comma separated values.

You want to split these CSV strings into their columns, but you don't want rows where any of your columns contain "?"

```
"A,?,B,C"      => do not use this one, one of the column values equals "?"
"A,B,C"        => use this one, none of the column values equal "?"
"A, Hello?, B" => use this one, although the second column contains a question mark
                  this second column is not equal to question mark
```

This is done as follows:

```
static readonly char[] separatorChars = new char[] {','}
const string questionMark = "?";
static readonly IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = 

var rowsWithoutQuestionMarkValues = userData

    // Split each line into column values, using comma as separator
    .Select(line => line.Split(separatorChar)

    // do not use the line if any of the columns equals the question mark
    .Where(splitLine => !splitLine.Any(column => column == questionMark));
```

If your code might be running in a culture where a questionmark might look differently, for instance: "分号", consider using an `IEqualityComparer<string>`

```
readonly IEqualityComparer<string> comparer = GetStringComparerForMyCulture();

var result = ...
    .Where(splitLine => !splitLine.Any(column => comparer.Equals(column, questionMark));
```